# ¿Cual es la contraparte del metodo animate() de Jquery en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy creando un *Contador de logro* con ayuda de un codigo que encontre por internet ; pero esta en **jQuery** y yo estoy trabajando en **Js Puro**. En unas lineas del codigo aparece lo siguiente :

```
$({Counter: 0}).animate({Counter: el.text()},{
   duration: 2000,
   easing: 'swing',
   step: function (){
      el.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter) + '%');
   }
});
```

¿Cual es la contraparte en **Javascript Vanilla** del metodo jQuery "animate()" para este codigo?

Comment: Es lo mismo: [elemento.animate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/animate)

Comment: Tienes razón ; pero existe un poco de incompatibilidad en algunos navegadores (https://caniuse.com/web-animation) ha aceptar ciertas funcionalidades.. Pero estas en lo correcto en lo que dices, gracias por el comentario..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se puede hacer de varias formas y basándose en los métodos setTimeOut o setInterval.
Por ejemplo, así en primera instancia y sin trabajarlo mucho:

```
class Contador{
    constructor(id, duracion, ini, fin){
    this.ini       = ini;
    this.fin       = fin;
    this.duracion  = duracion;
    this.el        = document.getElementById(id);
    this.intervalo = Math.round(duracion/(fin-ini));
    this.timer     = null;
    this.time      = 0;
    }
    swing(){
      return Math.sin(this.time/this.duracion * (Math.PI/2));
    }

    contar(){
    this.el.innerText= this.ini + '%';
    this.timer = setInterval(function(obj){
          obj.time += obj.intervalo;
          let incr = obj.swing();
          let counter = obj.ini + incr*(obj.fin-obj.ini);
          if(counter >= obj.fin){
              clearInterval(obj.timer);
              counter = obj.fin;
            } 
          obj.el.innerText= Math.ceil(counter) + '%';
          }, this.intervalo, this)
    }
}
var miContador = new Contador("c1",2000,0,100);
miContador.contar();
var miContador2 = new Contador("c2",2000,0,200)
miContador2.contar()
```

En la parte html se necesita un div con id="c1" y otro con div "c2".
**EDITO**
Corrijo algunos errores. Ahora si funciona para distintos contadores.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda y excelente respuesta , fue mucho más de lo que esperaba..

Comment: En caso que quisiera animar **varios contadores** en vez de uno, como ocurre al usar `document.getElementById("el")`  ¿como podria hacer? @juan

Comment: Llevas razón, hay un error de bulto imperdonable. He usado un valor constante en lugar de usar el argumento para el id del bloque contador. La idea es tener un objeto     con un bloque asociado por su id, cuyo valor va cambiando con el tiempo. No tiene que ser siempre el mismo bloque. En la edición lo he corregido.